# Installing Minecraft server from .exe instead of .jar

Tags: minecraft

Very new to minecraft, and I'm trying to install server 1.8 (protocol number 42)..

Not sure if the .jar file (mcversions.net) is the normal way to install, but can't get it to work - either double clicking or using

```
  java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui'
```

Minecraft 1.8 (client game) works on the same computer so I don't think it's a java versioning issue.

Is there an executable of the 1.8 server that can be used instead?   If not, would installing the latest version using the .exe and replacing the .jar with 1.8 work?

Comment: Às far as I know there is no .exe you can use. You have to start the .jar using a batch-file. Simply open your notepad, write ` 0
down vote
 

To start a minecraft server you normally make a batch file (under Windows).

Just put the crfatbukkit.jar or whatever Server you are using into a folder an make a .bat file using your notepad. Just write `java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true PAUSE` and save the file as .bat (not .txt). Then it should run fine

Comment: Thanks, that worked great!    I'd mark your comment as the answer but it doesn't let me.    BTW, using the internet archive I found that the 1.8.x server was available at that time as an .exe!

Comment: I have posted my comment as an answer as well. So you can mark this as an answer to avoid this (answered) question to pop up on the main page :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start a minecraft server you normally make a **batch** file (under Windows).

Just put the *crfatbukkit.jar* or whatever Server you are using into a folder an make a .bat file using your notepad. Just write

```
java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true PAUSE
```

into the file and save it in the folder of the craftbukkit.jar.